# Getting "Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)" in memory leak?

Tags: c, linux, shell, valgrind

Running the following C program with valgrind --leak-check=yes results in valgrind giving an output indicating that "Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)"

The following code is:

```
execv(commandCopy, cmd->argv);
fprintf(stderr, "%s: Command not found.\n", commandCopy);
free(cmd->argv);
free_cmd(cmd);
_exit(0);
```

According to valgrind, the problem occurs on the line:

```
==582489== Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==582489==    at 0x49630FB: execve (syscall-template.S:120)
==582489==    by 0x109FE5: parse_cmd (mysh.c:318)
==582489==    by 0x109C53: parse_cmd (mysh.c:228)
==582489==    by 0x10A25E: main (mysh.c:388)
```

What mistake have I made that causes valgrind to give this output?

Comment: You need to create a proper [mre] to show us. What is `cmd`? What is `cmd->argv`? How is `cmd->argv` initialized?

Comment: And considering that the second argument to [`execv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) should be `char * const *` doing `free(cmd->argv)` seems wrong. Also, if `execv` fails, it doesn't have to be that the command can't be found, there could be other reasons as well.

Comment: It continues to amaze me that posters cannot tell the difference between a leak and other kinds of memory error. Valgrind, at least, does have a clue, and includes the word “leak” in errors that are leaks. Does “Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)” include the word leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through this slowly.

- "syscall"

System calls (or syscalls) are the way that user code makes function calls into the kernel. Common system calls are `open`, `read`, `write`, `futex`. There are around 400 system calls.

- "param"

A parameter of the syscall.

- "execve"

System call that replaces the current executable with another one.

- "argv"

The argument vector, which is the arguments that will be passed to the new executable.

The man page says

argv is  an  array  of argument strings passed to the new program.  By
convention, the first of these  strings  should  contain  the  filename
associated  with the file being executed.  envp is an array of strings,
conventionally of the form key=value, which are passed  as  environment
to  the  new  program.  **Both argv and envp must be terminated by a NULL
pointer.**

(I added the bold).

- "uninitialised byte(s)"

Some memory hasn't been assigned a value.

Either your `argv` is `NULL`, or more likely, you forgot to `NULL` terminate the array of pointers to `char*` that makes up `argv`.